# Передача JSON посредством TCP

Tags: c++, c, json, сокет, tcp-ip

Всегда по ТСP (посредством обычных сокетов) передавал сериализованные данные в бинарном виде. Сообщение начиналось с заголовка и данных о длине сообщения. Но вот один из заказчиков желает чтобы данные передавались в виде JSON. И моя сторона только серверная. Как бы я вижу два варианта:

1. Писать заголовок и длину сообщения внутри JSON-строки (в самом начале). Недостаток - неудобно формировать строку, потому как длина еще неизвестна, а хотелось бы уже ее записать. Но это решаемо - просто неудобно.
2. Пробегать весь буфер в поисках конца JSON-строки. Грубо говоря, проверять на валидность содержимое буфера. Недостаток - очень большие накладные расходы на мой взгляд.

Так вот вопрос собственно в том, может кто-либо сталкивался с передачей JSON-строки "как есть" по ТСP посредством обычных сокетов и имеет опыт реализации.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37611/discussion-on-question-by-max-zs--json--tcp).

Answer (score -3):

У меня на пыхе есть что то подобное

```
$a = "Привет Мир!";
$json = json_encode($a);
socket_write($socket, $json);
```

И еще вариант ближе к сяшкам:

```
$a = "Привет Мир!";
$json = json_encode($a);
$len = strlen($json);
socket_send($socket, $json, $len, 0);
```

Если на Си++ пишете, то посмотрите модуль json под ваш язык, json стандарт который призван подружить системы на разных языках.